# Supporting manifest attributes from higher API level while building against lower API level?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an application which must be compatible with Android 2.1 (Eclair, API Level 7).  I want to use a manifest attribute which is only supported by Android 2.2+ (Froyo, API Level 8).   As a rule, I do not want to directly invoke (i.e., not via reflection) *ANY* Level 8 APIs from within my code.

The accepted solution to this problem is to compile against Froyo (API 8) and include a uses-sdk tag in the manfiest to indicate backward compatibility:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

The caveat is now we need to be careful and extensively test (via automated tests and/or manually) against Eclair to ensure we haven't accidentally used a Froyo-specific API call.

This is hardly an acceptable solution in my opinion.  I strongly prefer to only use reflection to invoke APIs above an application's baseline requirement, and only want to support manifest settings above the baseline.  Is there any means to cleanly and simply workaround this?

My current workaround is to remove manifest entries that are not compatible with the baseline API and perform a test compile before any public release.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

That's the best you can do right now.

That goes for using unsupported/deprecated attributes in layout files as well. There's no way you can put conditions within the Manifest file or any other resource files.

But, I don't think it's a big problem, at-least for now, since from now on, you will see a majority of users switching to the latest versions (4.0 and up).